# calculate array based on 100 max

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have a JS array like so...

```
var newArray = [20,182,757,85,433,209,57,828,635];
```

And I want to use this data to create a bar graph, where the height of the highest bar would == 100.
So, the 828 value bar needs to be set to 100, and the rest of the bars need to be calculated relative to that, and also to the closest integer. I am not sure how to go about this?

Is there a way to create a new array from the one above using a loop? Then I can use the new array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, calculate the max value:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, newArray.map(Math.abs));
// will do `Math.max(300, 20, 182, ...)`
// if `newArray` is `[-300, 20, 182]`
```

Then, divide each element by that value, do it times 100, and round it down so that the highest value becomes 100:

```
var normalized = newArray.map(function(v) {
  return Math.round(v / max * 100);
});
```

`.map` is essentially a loop, but the loop is done internally so you can write cleaner code. Do note it's ES5, so you need a shim for older browsers.

Comment: +1 for cool use of `Math.max()` and `.apply()` to get the max value in the array.

Comment: agreed, going to be re-factoring some code in a few minutes and this wasn't my question. :)

Comment: @pimvdb Bonus question: If the array contains a negative value, it cannot become the max... [-300,10,20]. For a chart, it would be ideal that the max is "300" for creating bar heights. How would I use max to get the greatest distance from 0 instead of the highest value?

Comment: @livinzlife: I think you're looking for `Math.abs`. See my edit. Though I'm unsure what the normalized value should be (`-100`?).

Comment: @pimvdb I ended up using both, abs to calculate the graph bar heights, and the other to actually setup the normalized values. Everything seems to be working great, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var max = newArray[0];

//determine max value
for (var i in newArray)
    if (newArray[i] > max) max = newArray[i];

//count coficients for every bar
var coefficients = [];
for (var i in newArray) 
    coefficients[i] = Math.round(newArray[i] / max * 100);
```

Comment: In this example, `coefficients` will be 0 to 1 (decimals).  I think the OP asked for 0 to 100 (integers).

Comment: Your coefficients are in the right range now, but still aren't integers.

Answer (score 1):

I like pimvdb's solution that uses no visible loops, but since you asked about loops, here's the loop-oriented way of doing it:

```
var newArray = [20,182,757,85,433,209,57,828,635];
var max = newArray[0];
var scaledArray = [];

// find max value
for (var i = 1; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    if (newArray[i] > max) {
        max = newArray[i];
    }
}

// create new scaled array (integer values from 0 to 100)
for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    scaledArray.push(Math.round(newArray[i] * 100 / max));
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ExWn8/